# Stuck in React-Native + Redux & Firestore Query

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux

Sorry i am a bit new to React Native and Firestore and couldn't able to rectify the issue in this part of code. So, need some expert help so that i will know what i am doing wrong and where. Basically, What i am trying to achieve here is that i want to show the result from my users table to my leaderboard page. In firestore my leaderboard collection 'doc' id is similar to the 'doc' id of users collection.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Block, Text } from '../../components';

import { fs } from '../../config/fbConfig'; 

class LeaderboardCard extends Component {

   state = {
       userFirstName : ''
   }

   render() {
       const {leaderboards} = this.props;
       //console.log(leaderboards)
       return (
           <Block>
               {leaderboards.map(leader => {
                   fs.collection('users').doc(leader.id).get().then(snap => {
                       return (
                           <Block key={leader.id}>
                               <Text>{leader.totalKills}</Text>
                               <Block>
                                   <Text>{snap.data().firstName}</Text>
                               </Block>
                           </Block>
                       )        
                   })
               })
               }
           </Block>
       )
   }
}

export default LeaderboardCard;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't include promise code (i.e. `doc().get().then(..` in your render code. You will have to load the data in a component lifecycle method like `componentDidMount` and after it loads save it to component state with `this.setState`.

Comment: i did that as well but .map function not waiting for the data coming from componentDidMount lifecycle method. can you please elaborate more about this. please

Comment: @azundo thanks for the suggestion dude.. when i deleted my whole code and write it again as you said. it's now working. :) Thanks

Comment: @azundo Thanks for the answer. Can you also post it as an answer below in order to make it more visible to the rest of the community?